# Site Specific Metas

Tags: discussion, android-app, per-site-meta

Not sure if I am missing how to do this on the android app but I don't see any easy way to access the site specific metas from the android app and can only seem to access my meta profiles or items that have appeared in my inbox. Is there something that I am overlooking or is it not possible to access meta sites from the android app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the left side drawer, select "All Sites", at the bottom of the drawer. Near the top of the ensuing screen, next to the search box, there's drop down menu. Change it to "Meta sites" or "All sites" instead of "Main sites" (the default).

Should also be noted that you can 'pin' a site to the left pull out drawer if you access it frequently but doesn't make the list. That's available from the "Edit" button next to "Your Sites" in the drawer.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now and got the meta pinned to the drawer now.